Half circle blended into bar with top shadow
What is the best approach to create this in HTML/CSS? Ideally, if this could be done with pure CSS and not any SVG images, it would be ideal.
The two biggest challenges are how the half-circle blends into the bar with a subtle curve and the top shadow.


Your question does not fit to the image you have posted. And in addition, the code you have tried is missing.  Without a minimal reproducible code, there is nothing much we can do to try and help you.

Maybe something like this? https://codepen.io/tonkec/pen/yLdQWvm

Apologies for my first sentence. Did not see the bar because of the low contrast. But the rest still applies.

https://css-shape.com/inner-curve/

@TemaniAfif I love the mask method but its an inner mask and not an outer. Also I am not able to box shadow a mask. Are you?
